# Please explain, function to add string to first line of a file

Tags: powershell

Would you like to explain what is happing in the PowerShell code at the bottom of this post?

I got my first, lets say "hello world" in PowerShell, and it needed these lines of code. It works like a charm, but I am not sure what it does, exactly.

The questions starts at

```
$( ,$_; Get-Content $Path -ea SilentlyContinue) | Out-File $Path
```

So this is what I understand so far.

We create a function called `Insert-Content`. With the params (input that will be interpeted as a string and will be added to `$path`).

```
function Insert-Content {
  param ( [String]$Path )
```

This is what the function does/processes:

```
process {
  $( ,$_;
```

I am not sure what this does, but I guess it gets "the input" (the "Hello World" before the `|` in `"Hello World" | Insert-Content test.txt`).

And then we got `-ea SilentylyContinue`, but what does it do?

```
process {
  $( ,$_; Get-Content $Path -ea SilentlyContinue) | Out-File $Path
```

It would be greatly appreciated if you could explain these two parts

> `$( ,$_;`
>   `-ea SilentylyContinue`

Code needed/used: Add a string to the first line of a doc.

```
function Insert-Content { 
  param ( [String]$Path )
  process {
    $( ,$_;Get-Content $Path -ea SilentlyContinue) | Out-File $Path
  } 
}

"Hello World" | Insert-Content test.txt
```

Comment: `-ea` is `-ErrorAction`. See `help about_common_parameters` for more about that.

Comment: Use code formatting (the `{}` tool) for blocks of code not quote formatting. Use backticks around code snippets within lines of text.

Comment: Thanks and the SilentylyContinue is also explained there ?

Comment: Yes, that's the argument to `-ea`.

Comment: `$(` isn't a thing by itself. It is `$( .... )` with arbitrary contents in the `....` part. `$_` is the default "this" variable in loops/process blocks/etc. I would expect most powershell tutorials to cover that at some point.

Comment: thanks,and a nice evening to you sir

Comment: I figured that much. but why does the  "," stand before the "$_" in the "$( ,$_; ....)"
is it because the function needs the string as a value?

Comment: @Ramon, have a look at the [`Comma operator` section on this page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx).

Comment: :-) insane, thanks you guys for the answer and the edits.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers Thanks a lot! And I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`process {...}`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh413265.aspx) is used for applying the code inside the [scriptblock](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847893.aspx) (the `{...}`) to each parameter argument that the function reads from a pipeline.

`$_` is an [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) containing the current object. The [comma operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) `,` preceding the `$_` converts the string value to a string array with a single element. It's not required, though. The code would work just as well with just `$_` instead of `,$_`.

`Get-Content $Path` reads the content of the file `$Path` and echoes it as to the [success output stream](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell.aspx) as an array of strings (each line as a separate string).

The `;` separates the two statements `,$_` and `Get-Content $Path` from each other.

`| Out-File $Path` writes the output back to the file `$Path`.

The [subexpression operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) `$()` is required to decouple reading the file from writing to it. You can't write to a file when a process is already reading from it, so the subexpression ensures that reading is completed before writing starts.

Basically this whole construct

> `$( ,$_;Get-Content $Path -ea SilentlyContinue) | Out-File $Path`

echoes the input from the pipeline (i.e. the `"Hello World"`) followed by the current content of the file `$Path` (effectively prepending the input string to the file content) and writes everything back to the file.

The [`-ea SilentlyContinue`](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/03/09/hey-scripting-guy-march-9-2010.aspx) (or `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`) suppresses the error that would be thrown when `$Path` doesn't already exist.

Comment: Thanks, both explanations are fine

Answer (score 2):

The relevant section of code must be handled as a whole:

```
$( ,$_;Get-Content $Path -ea SilentlyContinue) | Out-File $Path
```

First, as others have said, `-ea` is the shortened version of `-ErrorAction`.  `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` tells the cmdlet "Suppress any error messages and continue executing."  See `Get-Help about_Common_Parameters -ShowWindow`.

Next, the `$()` is the sub-expression operator.  It means "Evaluate what is between the parentheses as its own command and return the result(s)."  See `Get-Help about_Operators -ShowWindow`.

This subexpression here is:

```
,$_;Get-Content $Path -ea SilentlyContinue
```

It contains two statements:  `,$_` and `Get-Content $Path -ea SilentlyContinue`.  The semicolon is just the end of statement identifier to separate the two.

`,$_;` is two kind of complex parts.

`$_` is the special pipeline variable.  It always contains whatever object is in the current pipeline.  See `Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables -ShowWindow` for more about `$_` (it's mostly used with ForEach-Object and Where-Object cmdlets, so check those out, too), and `Get-Help about_pipelines -ShowWindow` for more help with pipelines.

The comma here is the comma operator (see `Get-Help about_Operators -ShowWindow` again).  It creates an array from the objects on either side.  For example, `1,2,3` creates an array with three elements 1, 2, and 3.  If you want a two item array, you can say `1,2`.

What if you want a one item array?  Well, you can't say `1,` because Powershell will think you forgot something.  Instead, you can say `,1`.

You can test it with the `-is` operator:

```
PS C:\> 1,2,3 -is [Array]
True
PS C:\> 1 -is [Array]
False
PS C:\> ,1 -is [Array]
True
```

Why might you want to create a one item array?  Well, if later on your code is assuming the item is an array, it can be useful.  In early editions of Powershell, properties like `.Count` would be missing for single items.

For completeness, yes, I believe you could write:

```
$( @($_);Get-Content $Path -ea SilentlyContinue)
```

And I think you could rewrite this function:

```
function Insert-Content { 
    param ( [String]$Path )
    process {
        #Read from pipeline
        $strings = @($_);

        #Add content of specified file to the same array
        $strings += Get-Content $Path -ea SilentlyContinue;

        #Write the whole array to the file specified at $Path
        $strings | Out-File $Path;
    }
}
```

So this adds content from the pipeline to the start of a file specified by `-Path`.

It's also somewhat poor practice not to create a parameter for the pipeline object itself and define it.  See... well, see all the topics under `Get-Help "about_Functions*"`, but mostly the Advanced ones.  This is an advanced topic.

Comment: Thanks, I can not rate it yet. But it is a fine explanation.